# Symmetric Matrices $B_{n \times n}$ of the form $A^{T}A$ for some matrix $A_{m \times n}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Is every symmetric matrix $B_{n \times n}$ of the form $A^{T}A$ for some matrix $A_{m \times n}$?

What I've done so far is:

For any matrix $A_{m \times n}$, the matrix $A^{T}A$ is symmetric because ($A^{T}A)^{T}=A^{T}(A^{T})^{T}=A^{T}A$, where the superscript T denotes the transpose of A. Not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Can you get $-1$ times the identity?

Comment: What Chris Godsil is alluding to is the fact that the answer to your question depends on which field the matrices are over.

Comment: -1 times the identity should be fine.

Comment: Another one: how would the exchange matrix $$\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$$ be handled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: for a real matrix $A$, $A^TA$ is always positive semidefinite.